# Publishing C# Console App as a stand-alone executable

Tags: c#, executable, publish

I am trying to publish my C# Console .Net Core App using VS 2019, .NET v5.0.
In
`bin\Release\net5.0\win-x64`  folder, there is an .exe executable but also other extensions. When I delete some of them, the executable does not run. I have tried both *self-contained* and *framework-dependent*. Is there a way to merge all the files to a stand-alone .exe or to publish as a  stand-alone executable?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/62086103/51685 ?

Comment: There I get 4 .dll files and a .pdb file with the .exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net whole application as a single .exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261942/net-whole-application-as-a-single-exe-file)

Answer (score 3):

You have to choose a specific target runtime and then under publish options - "Produce Single File".

[image: Publish explanation image]

Comment: I did that and it didn't work for me

Comment: hm the way actually worked for me. It created the .exe in the target location. Does it also not work for you in a fresh/new console application?

Comment: Yeah I tried with fresh consoles so many times, the .exe that has been created didn't run without the .dll files. Would the type of the project make any difference?

Comment: Dont think so. For me it was working right out of the box. I was creating a .Net 5 console app, right click on the project -> publish, Created a publish profile, then changed the target runtime and file publish option. After that i could find it in the target location bin\Release\net5.0\publish\

Comment: I can find it there too. I mean are you able to run it as a single file when you copy the .exe file and paste it to a different directory (like desktop)? In my case it shuts down upon starting. I tried with a few projects and result is the same.

Comment: Ok, so wait: Did you add sth. like Console.ReadLine() at the end of Main() ? For me it certainly shows the Hello World, no matter which directory I paste the .exe in.

Comment: That 'File publish options' section doesn't exist at all in my VS 2019.  Is there something I need to do to enable it or make it appear?